# I have two arrays and want to concat and send the data via post method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays one is of keys and one is of its values

```
a=[name,place,job],
b=[John,Atlanta,Engineer]
```

I want to concat a and b and send it by post method like

```
xyz={
'name':'John',
'place:'Atlanta',
'job':'Engineer'
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that `a` has 2 values and `b` has 3 values?

Answer (score 2):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyvkwh)

```js
 let a = ['name','place','job'];
 let b = ['John','Atlanta','Engineer'];
 let payload = a.reduce((obj, item, index) => (obj[item] = b[index], obj) ,{});
 console.log(payload);
```

Service

```
this.http.post<any>(this.URL, payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an source array and then create a object with key and value then use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

For ex:

```
  a = ["name", "place", "job"];
  b = ["John", "Atlanta", "Engineer"];

  xyz = {};

  constructor() {
    this.a.forEach((item, index) => {
      var obj = {
        [this.a[index]]: this.b[index] || ""
      };
      Object.assign(this.xyz, obj);
    });

    console.log(this.xyz);
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-uc4nvf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, who gave you the right to change an answer of someone? You can edit and suggest to change it, but not change it by yourself.

Comment: @AksenP this is perfectly ok. this is the same answer with just little check, no major change.

Comment: @AksenP Well, I am not sure is it about the rights or smthing else: I just corrected the answer becuase instead of posting a new answer *(by me)* with the minor change, I don't think it was needed so I just corrected or handled extra use-case!

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use `Object.assign` and `map` methods:

```js
let a = ['name','place','job'];
let b = ['John','Atlanta','Engineer'];

const result = Object.assign(...a.map((k, i) => ({[k]: b[i]})))
console.log(result);
```